# C# EF Update entites in one request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use a SQL Procedure to update many rows in one table based on a crieteria, here a date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [S_SourceProduct].P_U_SourceProductSetDisableBeforeDate
@UpdateDate DATETIME
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [S_SourceProduct].T_E_SourceProduct
SET [Disabled]=1
WHERE [S_SourceProduct].T_E_SourceProduct.UpdateDate <  @UpdateDate
```

I didn't do it with entity because I know only 2 ways:

- Retrieve all items and loop on each one => slower than my stored procedure with a lot of rows.
- Copy my procedure in a string and use it as string query => no build checking about syntaxe or column name and so on.

Is there an other except up both ?

Comment: You *can* use stored procedures with EF, btw.

Comment: you might find this helpful as a start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/2495283.  It's related to Bulk Inserts, but the principles are the same.

Comment: @Robert You right.Actualy, I do this way. But I'm looking for a way to generate the query with entity.

Comment: You mean you want to create the stored procedure in your DB if it does not exist yet?

Comment: @Claies Yes You are right, but this is the 1 first way I know. But this way is pretty slow with big amount of rows. Entity will send one query for each row even you use savechanges at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using an extension to Entity Framework, this can be achieved using [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

[For example](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete):

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");

//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(
    t => t.StatusId == 1, 
    t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});
```

Comment: exactely what I was looking for. If this extension works on azure I'm ok ?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, give it a go!